# How to compare a GUID with a string when both values are in SQL Server with EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql

I have a table structure where I have one table where the PK is a GUID, and a table `modificationslog` where this is a `varchar` column.

In SQL I can easily join these two tables like this.

```
SELECT * 
FROM ModificationsLog 
LEFT JOIN IAMUser ON CAST(IAMID AS VARCHAR(500)) = PrimaryKey
```

When I try to do this in LINQ, it is impossible since you can't do a `ToString()` on a GUID.

As far as I have found you therefore have 3 solutions to this, neither of witch is good.

1. Use a loop over `ModificationsLog`, then use new guid (primary key) before querying `IAMUser` for data (BAD performance with potentially many round trips)
2. Do a direct DB query with the above query (BAD maintainability if anything changes)
3. Create a view or stored procedure with the above query (probably best solution, still not good from a maintainability perspective)

Is there no alternative to write this as a single linq query? Ideally I'd like to write:

```
    var logs = from m in db.ModificationsLog
               join u in db.IAMUser on m.PrimaryKey equals u.IAMID.ToString() into j
               select j;
```

Based on the comments, this actually worked:

```
var logs = from m in db.ModificationsLog
            where m.ChangedTable == nameof(UserInfo) && m.PrimaryKey == primaryKey
            join u in db.IAMUser on m.ChangedBy equals u.IAMID.ToString() into j
            from user in j.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new { m, user  };
```

Comment: In my test (latest EF6.1.3) `Guid.ToString()` is succesfully translated to SQL (`(LOWER( CAST( [Table].[Column] AS nvarchar(max))))`).

Comment: Why isn't the value a Guid to begin with?  That seems like the core problem.

Comment: Because the ModificationsLog table is a generic log table where changes to a lot of tables are logged, and those tables has varying PK data formats (GUID or INT primarly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course is possible :

```
using(var _context = new MyDbContext()){
    var logs = _context.ModificationsLog.Where(ml => ml.PrimaryKey.Equals(ml.IAMUser.IAMID.ToString());
}
```

It can be a little different because you doesn't provide the models, but the logic is here

Comment: That code will cast a runtime exeption "Unable to cast the type 'System.Guid' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types."

Comment: I Forgot the ToString

Answer (score 0):

```
 using (yourContext db = new yourContext())
 {
   var logs = db.ModificationsLog.Join(db.IAMUser, x => x.PrimaryKey.ToString(), y => y.IAMID.ToString(), (x, y) => x).ToList();
 }
```